# Memory Handling for Object of Custom Class Which is inside Mutable Array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I searched about this question but can't found any suitable answer:
I had been working on `java` for a long time now i want to learn `Objective-C`

Here is the scenario:
I have an `Objective C` class which Extends `NSObject` class that class contains saveral fields of `NSString` type and `CustomObject` type i created there property with `@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString or MyObjec`t.
After creating object of my custom class i put it in NSArray as `[myArray addObject:myObject]`

now what i want to ask if i release myArray do i have to release objects inside that array and fields inside that object and some fields are too `CustomObject` of another class;

Comment: Have you considered using ARC, rather than the classic retain release? It would make thinking about this type of thing easier.

Comment: actually i want to use manual releasing instead of ARC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deallocate an NSArray a release message is sent to every object in the array. If the only reference to your object is in the array, then your object will call its dealloc method, which is in charge of releasing all of its properties.

Comment: okz if i have only one refrence which is in NSArray. if i release array will sub fields of custom class will also be release where those sub fields are also custom objects

Comment: Yes, so long as your custom object releases them in its dealloc method (which it likely should))

Answer (score 1):

I'm still learning objc and I think when you created your custom object the retain count bumps up and adding it to array adds up to the retain count as well. So when you release the object inside the array it still has a retain count that needs to be release. That's just my thought.

Comment: thaks for your answer but what about other custom objects which are associated with that object as there instance variables

Comment: just like Daniel's answer when you release an array, each object in the array will receive a release message and subtract a retain count.