# What is Objective C Equivalent for String.indexOf(String, startIndex)

Tags: objective-c

I have search for this but could not found in Apple documentation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want `- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask range:(NSRange)aRange`. The range argument is an NSRange indicating where in the haystack to look for the needle. Passing `NSMakeRange(startIndex, [haystack length]-startIndex)` should do what you want.

Comment: to get first index of String i used 
[myString rangeOfString:@"url_encoded_fmt_stream_map="];
this method returning int 2323223422 this index is impossible because my total characters in string are 4030 why this happening

Comment: You might want to start a new question about this. This method returns an NSRange, not an int. Are you checking the "location" member of this struct? Could it be equal to NSNotFound?

Comment: i was using .location with it and later i found it was returning index more than total length because it didnt found String. 
Thanks sub string function of Objective c is little different from Java in functionality point of view.
thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:searchString
                              options:0
                                range:NSMakeRange(startIndex, [string length]-startIndex)];
if (range.length != 0) {
    NSString* resultString = [string substringWithRange:range];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean you couldn't find [this documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) by searching `NSString` and clicking the first link?

```
NSString *substring = [string substringFromIndex:startIndex];
```

Comment: He probably didn't know it was called `NSString`

Comment: I checked his other questions first. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11027842/916299) makes explicit reference to NSString

Comment: Furthermore, the second link when just searching the question title returns a suitable answer, (the first now being this question).

Comment: Ouch, well I guess no more benefit of the doubt

Comment: i didnt mean that i could not found documentaion page. I read this documentation but could not understand it. and could not found example :)

Comment: I just looked at the page you linked and found `(NSString *)substringFromIndex:(NSUInteger)anIndex`. Could someone translate that into the syntax of how to get a substring from a string?